# An International English Olympiad question

Tags: confusables, analogy

I had recently appeared for an English Olympiad, and this particular question confused me:

Q) Choose the odd pair:

1. A. cat:feline

   B. monkey:simian

   C. horse:stallion

   D. cow:bovine

Now, the problem is that, in the 1st two options, the animals look like each other; but in the last two options, the animals are pairs.

Which is the correct option?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a very standard relationship question: a cat is feline, a monkey is simian, and a cow is bovine, but a horse is not (necessarily) a stallion. The parallel term for a horse would be *equine*.

Comment: I completely agree with you that a parallel term for horse should be _equine_, but a cow and bovine can be pairs in the same way as a horse and stallion. What do you think, Martha?

Comment: @Logophile: not with any meaning of "bovine" I know. A male bovine animal is a bull, and a neutered bull is a steer, so either cow:bull or cow:steer might be considered pairs, but all of them are equally described by "bovine".

Comment: Yeah, right. Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: @Logophile: perhaps what you’re thinking of is the fact that *bovine* can also function as a noun?  It’s true, it can; but so can *feline*, *simian*, *equine*, and they all still remain generic — if anything, more generic than *cat*, *horse*, etc. — unlike *stallion*, which is quite specifically a male horse.

Answer (score 9):

**Horse:stallion** is the odd one out.

*Feline* is an adjective, meaning “cat-like or related to cats”.

*Simian* is an adjective, meaning “monkey-like or related to monkeys”.

*Stallion* is a noun, meaning “male horse”.

*Bovine* is an adjective, meaning “cow-like or related to cows”.

[**Edit:** *feline*, *simian*, *bovine* can all also function as nouns, meaning “cat-like animal”, etc.]

Answer (score 0):

Between *feline*, *simian*, *stallion*, and *bovine*, *stallion* is the only word that is only a noun; the other words are both an adjective and a noun.